# Change Image's Background Color in HTML or CSS

Tags: css, html, web

I just downloaded an html template, in that I can see the images having white background, but when those are used in site, they have background color changed.

[image: Original Image]

And this is what I see in the site:

[image: Image in the site]

So How to achieve this effect, I spent whole night changing background color of an image in photoshop, that does not look as good as it is in this image,

So there must be some method in CSS to do this..?

Comment: please can you add siteurl where you used this pic?

Comment: What's the image file type? Possibly place the image inside of a div and style the div's background attributes? Not very clear question, sorry.

Comment: You need `.png` type `image` and then add `#img{ background: #aaf; }` in your css where `img` is `id` for container like `div` in which you've placed your `image`

Comment: ohh.. sorry for not being very clear, they have used .png images, so i guess @helpful's answer is to the point. Comments are also correct, they have used exactly same code as given by Vedant, thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by image type.  You likely need a PNG with transparency.  If you are familiar with photoshop, you just erase the background (so the alpha-layer can show through there) and then save an a png.  This will let the background color "show through" the image.

Comment: Don't 'erase' the background... mask it.

Comment: aahh.. it was using transparency.. I kept on changing entire images background 'by hand'.. silly me..

Comment: I was guessing (based on his question) he wasn't terribly familiar with image types/photoshop (or else he'd likely know how to use PNG's) so "erasing" to transparency is likely easier.  +1'd for the commend, though.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
img {
    background-color : blue;
}
```

This will appear on when you use a png transparent image.